# How to Get Total Count of Non-Swappable Pages in RAM?

Tags: swap, virtual-memory, ram

I am trying to debug some ML code that requires pinned physical memory, and in order to help with this, I would like to figure out how much of physical RAM consists of pages that can't be swapped out (i.e. non-swappable kernel pages, CUDA pinned pages, etc).

Specifically, I think each page is a member of 1 of 3 groups:

1. resides in physical RAM but can be swapped out
2. resides in physical RAM but cannot be swapped out
3. has been swapped out of physical RAM

I would like to know the size of group 2.

I have already looked it up and I learned about the `free` command, but I think `free` only tells you about groups 1+2 and group 3. Is there any way to specifically isolate group 2 in `free`, or is there some other way to find out how many pages cannot be swapped out?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the "meminfo" file in the proc pseudo-filesystem.  E.g. `cat /proc/meminfo`.  Look for the entries for "Unevictable" and "Mlocked".  I think that is what you are looking for.  `man proc` provides a little information, although these two entries have not received much documentation in the man page yet (at least not on my system).

I don't see a way to get the information you are looking for via the `free` command.

/proc/meminfo might not tell the full story, as described in https://docs.kernel.org/mm/unevictable-lru.html

> /proc/meminfo’s Unevictable and Mlocked amounts do not include those
> parts of a transparent huge page which are mapped only by PTEs in
> VM_LOCKED VMAs.